# Selecting options from drop down list in python using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the `SELECT` class utility with all it's functions including `selectByVisibleText()` and others but no success. Following is the div hierarchy of my elements and then is the `<select>` box which I want to read.

```
<div class="abc">
  <div class="def">
    <div class="xyz">
       <div></div>
       <select class="qwe" id="asd">
         <option class="zxc" label="test" value="01">01</option>
and options are so on till value 12.
```

How do I get to select the options using selenium webdriver in python ??

EDIT 1: The code I tried is as follows:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("asd"))
select.select_by_visible_text('04')
```

And,

```
 eMonth = browser.find_element_by_id("asd")
 eMonth.send_keys("10")
```

Comment: you tried it, what was the result? any error messages? pls include it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select` class with explicit wait

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
dropDown = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'asd')))
select = Select(dropDown)
select.select_by_value('01')
```

By the way, `selectByVisibleText()` is Java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly select class will work as drop down has select tag. good to have some info like code used and exception faced. i hope you tried with giving wait if fails, sleep.

we can also select drop down values by using sendkeys. below is the command is java

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("asd")).sendKeys("01");
```

Thank You,
Murali